# Remove Meteor.js Proxy settings

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, proxy

So I have figured out how to set proxy settings for Meteor.js as follows:

```
export HTTP_PROXY=http://user:password@1.2.3.4:5678
export HTTPS_PROXY=http://user:password@1.2.3.4:5678
meteor update
```

However, I have been looking tirelessly to find how to undo (remove) proxy settings that I configured on Meteor.js but can't seem to find the answer. **How can you remove proxy settings for Meteor.js??**

Please help!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you are asking, but this will reset the proxy settings:

```
export HTTP_PROXY=
export HTTPS_PROXY=
meteor update
```